# DNS set-up for an OpenShift cluster

Tags: dns, openshift, virtualbox

I am attempting to set-up an OpenShift cluster, with Virtual Machines, as described [here](http://v1.uncontained.io/playbooks/installation/#cluster-design-architecture). These VMs will be hosted on VirtualBox. In this article, under DNS, it says,

> All of the hosts in the cluster need to be resolveable via DNS. Additionally if using a control node to serve as the ansible installer it too should be able to resolve all hosts in your cluster.

I have started up setting up DNS server with BIND9 [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-bind-as-a-private-network-dns-server-on-ubuntu-18-04). Can I apply the BIND9 installation instructions for the cluster? Should the DNS server set-up on one of the master nodes? A separate VM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For both OpenShift 3.X and 4.X it should be set up in a separate place (VM, Raspberry Pi, etc) and A and PTR records should be set up for all the cluster hosts, the public api endpoint, the private api endpoint, and the HAProxy ingress controller.

Note: If you're deploying Openshift 4.X the documentation on uncontained.io will be a little out of date as Red Hat consulting catches up their documentation. The installation and management mechanisms for OpenShift 3.X and 4.X are drastically different.

If you're deploying OpenShift 4.1 you'll also need A records and SRV records for etcd.

Documentation for OpenShift 4.1 bare-metal DNS requirements can be found [here](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.1/installing/installing_bare_metal/installing-bare-metal.html#installation-dns-user-infra_installing-bare-metal)

An example dnsmasq setup I've used for a single master single worker OpenShift 4.1 bare-metal cluster with `cluster_name: ocp4` and `base_domain:example.com` and a utility server serving as the DNS server, DHCP server, Load Balancer, and PXE server might look like:

```
no-hosts
domain=example.com,10.0.10.0/24,local
auth-zone=example.com,10.0.10.0/24

host-record=ocp4-utility.example.com,10.0.10.10
host-record=ocp4-master.example.com,10.0.10.11
host-record=ocp4-worker,10.0.10.12
host-record=ocp4-bootstrap,10.0.10.13

host-record=api.ocp4.example.com,10.0.10.10
host-record=api-int.ocp4.example.com,10.0.10.10

host-record=etcd-0.ocp4.example.com,10.0.10.11
srv-host=_etcd-server-ssl._tcp.ocp4.example.com,etcd-0.ocp4.example.com,2380,0,10

address=/apps.ocp4.example.com/10.0.10.10
```

Here is the HAProxy configuration for the "load balancer" running on the utility server:

```
global
    log         127.0.0.1 local2
    chroot      /var/lib/haproxy
    pidfile     /var/run/haproxy.pid
    maxconn     4000
    user        haproxy
    group       haproxy
    daemon

defaults
    mode                    tcp
    log                     global
    option                  tcplog
    retries                 3
    timeout http-request    10s
    timeout queue           1m
    timeout connect         10s
    timeout client          1m
    timeout server          1m
    timeout http-keep-alive 10s
    timeout check           10s
    maxconn                 3000

listen stats
    bind :9000
    mode http
    stats enable
    stats hide-version
    stats realm Haproxy\ Statistics
    stats uri /haproxy_stats
    stats auth admin:admin

frontend kubernetes_api
    bind 0.0.0.0:6443
    default_backend kubernetes_api

backend kubernetes_api
    balance roundrobin
    option ssl-hello-chk
    server bootstrap 10.0.10.13:6443 check
    server master 10.0.10.11:6443 check

frontend machine_config
    bind 0.0.0.0:22623
    default_backend machine_config

backend machine_config
    balance roundrobin
    option ssl-hello-chk
    server bootstrap 10.0.10.13:22623 check
    server master 10.0.10.11:22623 check

frontend router_https
    bind 0.0.0.0:443
    default_backend router_https

backend router_https
    balance roundrobin
    option ssl-hello-chk
    server worker 10.0.10.12:443 check

frontend router_http
    mode http
    option httplog
    bind 0.0.0.0:80
    default_backend router_http

backend router_http
    mode http
    balance roundrobin
    server worker 10.0.10.12:80 check
```

Comment: I will be building the OpenShift 3.x cluster as the Ansible approach is 'easier'. Any suggestions on setting up the A and PTR records for OpenShift 3.x?